# Creating so files from Android Project and loading them in the other project

Tags: android, android-studio, package, loadlibrary, cmake-modules

I had developed an Android application and in that I had a Library in which a java class file and one method in that takes the Image Bitmap and rotates the image by 180 degrees and returns the rotated bitmap Image. I can do this operation in my application as well. But I want to convert this Libraries into .so files and access this libraries using .so files from the Other application with different package. How can I do that and what are the steps that I need to follow. I had seen many stackoverflow questions and githug pages but none of them are working fine.

Through Package manager I can get the Application info of the first application from second application but How can I load my libraries that are present in first application from the second application.

I able to get all the SharedLibraries using

```
List<SharedLibraryInfo> reqinfo = this.getPackageManager().getSharedLibraries(1);
```

But I am not sure from where it is listing that libraries I want only the libraries that I created in the first application to be loaded in the second application. ow can I achieve that ?